# Compress php script before upload to main server

Tags: php

How can we compress php script before upload to main server so that our web site will become so fast to browse & reduce page downloading time..?

Thanks.

Comment: That reduces upload time, not download time.

Comment: did you mean that you want to cache requested pages so the php script doesn't have to execute again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. You probably meant to compress the output of your website. You can add a mod GZIP  handler to your Apache configuration, provided you run your site on Apache. Add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

Answer (score 12):

PHP runs entirely on the server-side, so compressing it will not reduce page download time.

Comment: Since PHP files often have code embed in HTML templates, you could minify the HTML part of the files to save a few bytes but I wouldn't bother. To reduce the compilation overhead you could also install an opcode cache.

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin: Right. This small improvement will have very few to no impact on performance. It is much more important what PHP does. Optimizations should be done there.

Comment: @elusive Sure. And you can't depend on automated tools to optimize your code.

Answer (score 4):

Compressing a PHP file will not speed up it's execution time.

By default, PHP will read the entire file each time, compile it to bytecode, then run that bytecode.

What you are probably looking for is a bytecode cache like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).  It will cache the bytecode that is generated so it does not need to be created each time.

Answer (score 1):

We've used NuSphere PhpExpress - Free PHP accelerator (http://www.nusphere.com/products/index.htm). It compiles PHP. It also requires an extension add-on for the server. It does speed pages up (a LITTLE), and it also protects them from being 'shared' (as the code is 'hidden').

There are better ways to increase the speed of you website though (see post by TheGrandWazoo) or by making sure your database table are optimized, queries and pages cached when feasible.